Integrate svelte-image with Cloudflare pages + R2
I'm currently working on a SvelteKit project that is hosted on Cloudflare Pages. I want to optimize and serve images from Cloudflare R2 instead of directly from the /static directory. My goal is to upload all static assets, except images, to Cloudflare Pages and upload images to Cloudflare R2 for better optimization and delivery. I want to use svelte-image to optimize my images.
Here is my current svelte.config.js:
import adapter from "@sveltejs/adapter-static";
import { vitePreprocess } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({
      pages: "build",
      assets: "build-assets",
      fallback: undefined,
      precompress: false,
      strict: true,
    }),
    alias: {
      $components: "src/components",
      $stores: "src/stores",
    },
  },
};

export default config;

The things I need that I am not sure how to achieve:

How can I make it so that when I push to GitHub, the build folder is pushed to Cloudflare Pages, and build-assets are uploaded to a Cloudflare R2 bucket.
How can I make sure the paths are correct, so that I can use local paths in the svelte-image components, and that they are correctly using the R2 URL after they are published.

Currently I have just connected my Cloudflare pages to Github, and on Cloudflare, I run npm run build when I push to build my website
